# Metabot do chat com links para as perguntas em HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-intencional, chat

Estava agora no chat do site, mas por HTTPS:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha

E, ao que parece, estando no chat por HTTPS, o metabot também repassa os links das perguntas do meta em HTTPS que depois não funcionam ao clicar:

- [Metabot do chat com links para as perguntas em HTTPS](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5268/metabot-do-chat-com-links-para-as-perguntas-em-https)

PS: *O chat não deveria ser sempre por HTTPS?*

Comment: Acho que eles nunca conseguiram implementar 100% de suporte a HTTPS

Comment: @bfavaretto é mais a 1% ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chat bots geram links relativos ao protocolo, então se você está no chat por HTTP o link vai ser gerado com HTTP, e o mesmo vale pra HTTPS.

Nós estamos em processo de migração de toda a rede pra HTTPS, mas [dá trabalho](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) e existem alguns problemas - principalmente envolvendo os Metas - que ainda precisam ser resolvidos.

Comment: Até agora não entendi a origem do problema. O chat e o site aqui sempre abriram em conexão normal, nunca vi link https do meta, do so ou do chat. Acho que isso é ação de plugin de navegador.

Comment: @diegofm O Jorge B acessa o chat por HTTPS, e por isso os links do Medabot são gerados com HTTPS - porque o Medabot é programado pra manter o mesmo protocolo.

Comment: Ah, então é por opção. Aqui o site só entra em https se eu alterar manualmente a URL, ou usando o tal plugin https everywhere que muda tudo pra https(se disponivel).

Comment: @diegofm ao fazeres login também é https. Eu uso https no chat de propósito mesmo.

Comment: Então @Gabe é esperar que o meta funcione em HTTPS?

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim. Mover os Metas pra HTTPS é *justamente* onde o problema tá agora, na migração da rede inteira pra HTTPS. É o próximo passo, mas não há uma previsão.

Comment: @Gabe pronto era para saber se punha a resposta como certa.